# Send value from view to action in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to send my itemID from my Detail View to an action method in my controller.
This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<GDMfrontEnd.Models.items>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detail";
}

<h2>Detail</h2>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_description)
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_title)
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_createddate)
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.deliverables.projects.project_name)
    }

    <a href="@Url.Action("Deliverable", "Bookmark", new { id =  }))">Add to favorites</a>
    </fieldset>
```

Now I would like to send the item.item_id tothe action "bookmark" in my deliverable controller. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_description)
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_title)
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_createddate)
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.deliverables.projects.project_name)
  <a href="@Url.Action("Deliverable", "Bookmark", new { id = item.item_id }))">Add to favorites</a>
}
```